# Flex Grid display data to gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I wont to Use Winform application. I will be use Flexgrid for Gridview so where is download this component one Dll file.

Comment: what exactly is your question? please put some effort in...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you asking where you can download the ComponenOne FlexGrid?
If so you can download it [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8851E2FE-37A5-4DD5-9A2E-AE2D3D83FF9D):

Comment: Don't answer bad questions please.  It just makes them think they can keep on asking the same way.

Comment: JK. your Thinking Is Very Bed...

Comment: If You dont know answer so Quetion Is Not Bed..